# list() a function? Or class name?

Tags: python, list, function, class, object

You are already aware of list() used in python. We use it to create a list either an empty one or from other iterables such  as tuple, set, etc.

Consider the following :

```
list1=list()
t=(1,2,3)
list2=list(t)
```

My major doubt here is, the name 'list' is a separate function named list or name of the class 'list'?

The reason for my doubt is, the syntax for creating an object is :

```
obj_name=class_name()
```

We have created the objects list1 and list2 as given in the syntax

Also

```
help(list)

Output : 
Help on class list in module builtins:

class list(object)
     .....
     .....
     .....
     __hash__=None
```

Gives the information only about the class list. Whereas for other built-in functions such as len(), the help() gives the functions' information

```
help(len)

Output : 
Help on built-in function in module builtins:

len(obj, /)
     Return the number of items in a container.
```

Hence, Is list() used as class name here to define its object???

Or is there a separate function to create a variable of type 'list' named list()???

To be more specific in my question, in the above code, Does list() acts as a class name or a function name?

If it is a built in function, can l get the code written for it???

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://pythonbasics.org/constructor/

Comment: It's a class, not a function. Classes are just objects, like everything else in Python, `int` objects, `dict` objects, even function objects and class objects. All classes are instances of `type` which itself is a class (a metaclass, a class that creates classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) is a [built-in class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#classes-and-class-instances) and the scope-name `list` is a reference to the `list` class. Invoking `list(...)` is implicitly calling the constructor of this class, `list.__init__()` which creates a new object instance of a list from optionally supplied arguments. There is only one `list` variable that is available in the global scope - it is a *class*, not a *function*.

See the following Python REPL output:

```
# the 'list' definition is a class, not a function
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>

# lists are actually instances of the 'list' builtin class.
>>> type(list())
<class 'list'>
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
```

Globally scoped built-ins such as `len` are a built-in function and not a class; i.e. it is not a constructor and does not initialize a new object instance.

See the following Python REPL output:

```
>>> type(len)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

This built-in function is different from a function declared in Python.

See the following Python REPL output:

```
>>> def test():
...    ...
...
>>> type(test)
<class 'function'>
```

---

The source code for `list` is implemented natively in C, and is available on the GitHub repository: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

---

For more documentation about what the types are for built-ins, check the following reference materials:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#built-in-consts
- JetBrains' generated skeletons for Python's standard library: https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/blob/master/builtins.py

Comment: Wow, this is what I needed. Moreover, list() is a constructor. Then why should we include that among the list of built-in functions??? See here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list

Comment: In languages like Java, a `new` keyword is needed for instantiating objects  (e.g. `new ArrayList<>(...)`); without `new`, it looks for a method instead. Python takes a different approach with constructing new object instances. Classes are both a class and a sort of pseudo-function. When invoking a class (e.g. `list()`), a new object is created by executing the class's internal `__init__` function. Functionally, there is no difference - an invocation of `list()` takes in arguments and returns data, much like any other function; it's just not _technically_ a "function" in the normal sense.

Comment: It can be in the normal sense. But, the official python website tells that. How??? They know it's internal structure and functionality right??

Comment: @SanmithaSadhishkumar I suppose you can consider classes to be a _special_ type of function, not to be confused with an explicitly declared function with `def func():`. For practical purposes, whether it is a class, builtin function, or `def`'d function, the end result is effectively the same. Invoking any of these takes in arguments and possibly returns a value - the core concept behind a function. To reiterate - there is only one `list()` definition in the global scope - and it is a class, a _special_ type of function that has more complex invocation behind the scenes.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

`list` is the name in the built-in scope bound to the type. Like most types, `list` is callable to create a new instance of the type. The argument it expects is an arbitrary iterable value used to populate a new list.

```
>>> type(list)
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(list((1,2,3,)))
<class 'list'>
>>> type(list(range(3)))
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm satisfied with the above answers. I even awarded bounty for the most suitable answer. But I even had certain doubts in that answer and he answered too. I want to provide an another answer to my question and I wanted to compile all those as an answer.

First of list() is a class name more specifically a type name. It is not a function. I'm sure about it. Similarly other datatypes such as bool, int, float, complex, set, tuple, dictionary, frozenset, str, etc are also classes.

To verify my point, just use help():

```
>>>help(list) # or any type you want
```

It gives the description of that class list.

Sometimes we have a doubt. If list() is not a function then why it is included in the list of built-in functions provided by the official website of python. [www.python.org](http://www.python.org)

Here is it link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

This was the question raised by me too.

My answer was. It is traditional. Once they were functions. Check here : https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node26.html#SECTION003300000000000000000

So they followed the same even in this version.

Hope this helps the readers